# Cloud Storage - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource for AngularJS view

Tags: cors, cross-domain, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

According to Chrome dev tools, my requests to get my html partials have the origin header https://site-name-here.com and request header GET.
I have the following JSON file set to my bucket:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://site-name-here.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["content-type"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

However, whenever angular tries to get the view, I get the following error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/view-path.html?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://site-name-here.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I am also serving javascript and css files from Cloud Storage, but they're working fine, I assume because CSS doesn't have CORS restrictions and I'm using $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist() in Angular for the scripts?

**Edit**: Working now, I'm assuming something was cached and it was serving me an old version.

Comment: If you set this policy on your bucket and then hit it directly, say via `curl -H "Origin: https://site-name-here.com" https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/view-path.thml`, do you see the header? I just tried to replicate this problem with that exact JSON file and saw the header every time I included the origin header in my request, as expected.

Comment: Hmm, it's working now in the browser too. I'm guessing something was cached even though I refreshed my Chrome cache.

Comment: You might want to consider adding a self-answer with your results and theory for why it occurred.

Comment: Related: It seems `gsutil cors set` will NOT warn you if you set an invalid policy. For example, we forgot to include the `responseHeader` key and `gsutil` failed to tell us that there was a problem.

Answer (score 17):

Just to support @Idcmp's answer, the CORS policy does take a while before taking full effect (this is not documented tho). I've spent ~2 hours trying to figure out why I'm still getting CORS error in browser even though I use the below policy (which is highly NOT recommended, but it's fine for my personal testing project).

```
{
    "cors": [
      {
        "origin": [
          "*"
        ],
        "method": [
          "*"
        ],
        "responseHeader": [
          "*"
        ],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
      }
    ]
}
```

ps Take a coffee break after applying a new CORS policy, you definitely deserve it

Answer (score 5):

As a summary for people who find this question via Google, applying a CORS policy seems to take a bit of time before it takes effect. Answers above indicate it could be due to intermediate caches, etc -- things that are likely out of your immediate control.

If you can, apply a CORS policy (via `gsutil`) that allows a wildcard origin and test your request either via https://www.test-cors.org/ or `curl --verbose --output /dev/null -H "Origin: https://your.actual.origin.here" https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/object` you will eventually see headers you're looking for:

```
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length, Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding, X-GUploader-UploadID, X-Google-Trace
```

Once it works, restrict the origins and methods you're actually using so you don't wind up on the news and/or have a surprisingly large bandwidth bill.

If you've done this and are still having issues, try uploading an object with a new name to the bucket (that is 100% not cached anywhere) to test.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, this type of issue can potentially be resolved upon clearing the browser or other intermediary service’s cache.

In case your application is running on a Google App Engine instance, it is possible to clear its intermediate cache by redeploying a new version of the app. Alternatively, it may be also possible to set a `default_expiration` or simple `expiration` of files cached within web proxies and browsers (see this Static cache expiration [section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#static_cache_expiration) of the app.yaml reference for more information).

Answer (score 1):

The following got it working for me:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://site-name-here.com"],
      "responseHeader": "*",
      "method": ["GET"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

Comment: A little more explanation would be nice because I don't know where to put this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might not be from the CORS configuration but from other errors being masked by CORS error.

To rule out problems with your configuration, check the CORS configuration of your bucket with this command - `gsutil cors get gs://BUCKET_NAME`. If your configuration is visible, then it's definitely not a configuration issue.

On the other hand, CORS might be masking other `4xx` or `5xx` errors returned by Cloud storage. This is because errors returned by Cloud storage do not have the access control headers set.

To see the real `4xx` and `5xx` errors on your browser, Try to disable the CORS check. A lot of plugins can assist with disabling CORS on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If cache is the problem, try this.

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control:no-cache" gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME
```

[Viewing and editing object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata)

Cache may remain somewhere in the network for a while.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. I used gsutil to set this CORS policy for my GCP storage bucket .Remove the cache of angular web application before you give it a try after setting the cors policy for more info see [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#server-side-support).

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://site-name-here.com"],
      "responseHeader": "Content-Type",
      "method": ["GET"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have request + preflight you might need to set additional parameters.

`"responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept","Authorization","Content-Length", "X-Requested-With"],`

[image]

[image]

https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/cors/

**Full CORS configuration:**

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "HEAD"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept","Authorization","Content-Length", "X-Requested-With"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```